# Rails: JSON attribute is handled as a method. No method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having problems accessing the attributes of my JSON data. Instead of accessing the JSON data it thinks it is a function.

```
 @response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:4000/test')
 @json = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  @json.each do |pet|
  MyModel.create(pet)       ! WORKS
  puts "my object #{pet}"   ! WORKS
  puts "my object attribute #{pet.myattribute}" ! DOES NOT WORK
  end
```

With no `MethodError myattribute`.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does `pet` look like?

Comment: `{"pet_id": "49926", title: "my Title"}` . When accessing `pet_id` it says `NoMethodError`. `NoMethodError: undefined method pet_id' for #<Hash:0x00000105347cf8>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@json = JSON.parse(@response.body)` returns a hash, so you would need to do

```
puts "my object attributes #{pet['id']}, #{pet['title']}"
```

you might want to convert to [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) so you can use symbols instead of quoted strings, i.e.

```
@json = JSON.parse(@response.body).with_indifferent_access
# ...
puts "my object attributes #{pet[:id]}, #{pet[:title]}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Working now with `pet['title']`

Answer (score 2):

You may be used to JavaScript, where both `object.some_key` and `object["some_key"]` do the same thing. In Ruby, a hash is just a hash, so you have to access values via `object["some_key"]`. A `Struct` in Ruby is similar to a JavaScript object, in that you can access values both ways, but the keys have to be pre-defined.